# Function that specifies argument of another function and list of values to pass to that argument with purrr::map or lapply

Tags: r, functional-programming, tidyverse, purrr

Suppose I have a simple function:

```
my_c <- function(x = 1, y = 2, z = 3) {
  c(x, y, z)
}
```

Now I want to create another function that wraps `my_c` and allows me to:

1. Choose which argument of the function I want to change
2. Supply a list of values to that argument

The desired output of this new function, `vary_my_c`:

```
vary_my_c(vary = "y", values = list(10, 11))
[[1]]
[1] 1  10  3

[[2]]
[1] 1  11  3
```

My attempts are to try to parse an expression but aren't working:

```
library(tidyverse)
vary_my_c <- function(vary, values, ...) {
  values %>% map(function(param) {
    my_c(eval(parse(text = str_c(vary, "= param"))))
  })
}
# or equivalently with syntactic sugar:
vary_my_c <- function(vary, values, ...) {
  values %>% map(~ my_c(eval(parse(text = str_c(vary, "= .x")))))
}
# gives:
[[1]]
[1] 10  2  3

[[2]]
[1] 11  2  3
```

I am wondering whether the solution involves `rlang::enquo()` and `!!` instead of `eval(parse(text = text))` but am not familiar enough with quasiquotation to figure out how to test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first attempt in the question would work if the line starting with `my_c` were replaced with:

```
eval(parse(text = sprintf("my_c(%s = %s)", vary, param)))
```

While that would work I suggest instead to use `Map` and `do.call`.  No packages are needed and `eval` is not used.

(purrr `map` and `invoke` in place of `Map` and `do.call` could alternately be used with appropriate rearrangement of arguments.  Quasi-quotation is not needed.)

```
vary_my_c <- function(vary, values) {
  Map(function(value) do.call(my_c, setNames(list(value), vary)), values)
}

vary_my_c(vary = "y", values = c(10, 11))
```

giving:

```
[[1]]
[1]  1 10  3

[[2]]
[1]  1 11  3
```